# How can I get the status ID using tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, jupyter-notebook, tweepy

I am using academic account to retrieve tweet information but I don't know how to get the status_id, I thought the conversation_id would be the same as status_id but when I track back, apparently it is not. What should I add to the tweet field?

```
for response in tweepy.Paginator(client.search_all_tweets,
                                     query = 'query -is:retweet lang:en',
                                     user_fields = ['username', 'public_metrics', 'description', 'location'],
                                     tweet_fields = ['created_at', 'geo', 'public_metrics', 'text','id','conversation_id'],
                                     expansions = ['author_id', 'geo.place_id'],
                                     start_time = ['2020-01-01T00:00:00Z'],
                                     end_time = ['2020-12-12T00:00:00Z']):
time.sleep(1)
tweets.append(response)

result
```

Answer (score 1):

You've already got it - "id" is the status id

> Tweets are the basic atomic building block of all things Twitter.
> Tweets are also known as “status updates.” The Tweet object has a long
> list of ‘root-level’ attributes, including fundamental attributes such
> as id, created_at, and text

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet

It may be a bit confusing because references to that id are labeled things like "in_reply_to_status_id" - but there is no field called "status_id" - it's just id.

Comment: Thanks @James_SO Still, I don't understand when I use the "ID" to track back through the hyperlink (https://twitter.com/"user_ID"/status/"ID"), the post could not be found if using the hyperlink with the "ID". It seems like the "ID" in the hyperlink is different from the one returned through the tweepy.

Comment: Please provide more source code (what does your Tweepy API call look like?) and an example (e.g. what does your id look like?)

Comment: I have updated the code. Both ID and conversation_ID are 19 digits. Those digits are not the same as appeared in the hyperlink (19 digits after status: https://twitter.com/Cell_Metabolism/status/1577327071030042625).